# Better way to do corelated query having count in condition in AWS Athena sql

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

There are two table A and B. Table A has one to many relationship with B.

1. I want to fetch records from A and corresponding one single record from B (if B has one record),
2. If there is multiple record in Table B then find the one having status ='Active' find first.

Below is the query, running in oracle, but we want the same functionality running in AWS Athena, however correlated query is not supported in AWS athena sql. Athena supports ANSI Sql.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM A a ,B b
WHERE a.instruction_id = b.txn_report_instruction_id AND b.txn_report_instruction_id IN
(SELECT b2.txn_report_instruction_id FROM B b2
WHERE b2.txn_report_instruction_id=b.txn_report_instruction_id
GROUP BY b2.txn_report_instruction_id 
HAVING COUNT(b2.txn_report_instruction_id)=1
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT b.*
FROM A a , B b
WHERE a.instruction_id = b.txn_report_instruction_id AND b.txn_report_instruction_id IN
(SELECT b2.txn_report_instruction_id
FROM B b2
WHERE b2.txn_report_instruction_id=b.txn_report_instruction_id
AND b2.status ='ACTIVE'
GROUP BY b2.txn_report_instruction_id
HAVING COUNT(b2.txn_report_instruction_id)> 1
)
)
```

We need to put all the field in select or in aggregate function when using group by so group by not preferable.
A help would be much appreciated.

[image] [[image]]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVtqh.png)
Output result table
[image]

Comment: Please Edit your question to include an example of data in both of the tables and the results you would like to get from the query based on that sample data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have attached the sample data and output tables. I hope this is helpful for your reference. Glad that you responded .

Comment: Next time, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text here instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Apologies. Can you suggest me online sql tool where I can create table and attach it here for reference.

Comment: I use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to get from the tab-separated lists I get from copying the data from my SQL tool to a readable format. For stackoverflow choose the output format "Github Markdown".

Answer (score 0):

Joining the best row can be achieved with a lateral join.

```
select *
from a
outer apply
(
  select * 
  from b
  where b.txn_report_instruction_id = a.instruction_id
  order by case when b.status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 2 end
  fetch first row only
) bb;
```

Another option is a window function:

```
select *
from a
left join
(
  select 
    b.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by txn_report_instruction_id 
                       order by case when status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
  from b
) bb on bb.txn_report_instruction_id = a.instruction_id and bb.rn = 1;
```

I don't know about amazon athena's SQL coverage. This is all standard SQL, however, except for `OUTER APPLY` I think. If I am not mistaken, the SQL standard requires `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (...) ON ...` instead, for which you need a dummy `ON` clause, such as `ON 1 = 1`. So if above queries fail, there is another option for you :-)